# How to combine 2 reducers right with combineReducers?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

So, I'm trying to figure out how `combineReducers` work, but now I cannot understand why I cannot set the current `state` from the reducer `weather` in reducer `loadMore` when it has been updated.

P.S.
In the reducer `weather` new state pushes normally.

reducer WEATHER:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionsTypes'

let initialState = {
    city: '',
    weather: [],
    loadMore: 5
};

const weather = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_WEATHER:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                city: action.cityName,
                weather: [
                    ...action.cityWeather
                ],
                loadMore: 5
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default weather;
```

reducer LOAD-MORE:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionsTypes'

let initialState = {
    city: '',
    weather: [],
    loadMore: 5
};

const loadMore = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_MORE:
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                ...state, // when I click 'load more' the state is empty
                loadMore: action.loadMore
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default loadMore;
```

reducer INDEX:

```
import * as types from '../constants/ActionsTypes'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import weather from './addWeather';
import loadMore from './loadMore';

const reducers = combineReducers({
    weather,
    loadMore
});

export default reducers;
```

container loadMore:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { moreWeather } from '../actions'
import loadMoreComponent from '../components/loadMore'

const mapStateToProps = state => (console.log('loadMoreComponent', state), {
    state: state.weather
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   moreWeather: (loadMore) => dispatch(moreWeather(loadMore))
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps)(loadMoreComponent);
```

container WeatherLayout:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import WheatherLayoutComponent from '../components/WheatherLayout'

const mapStateToProps = state => (console.log('WheatherLayoutComponent ', state), {
   cityStore: state.weather
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps, 
    null)(WheatherLayoutComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify things a bit i am renaming your reducers to end with`Reducer`.
The way `combineReducers` works is accepting an object for example `{ weather : weatherReducer, loadMore: loadMoreReducer}` and returning a reducer which will return a state in the form :

```
(state, action) => ({
   weather: weatherReducer(state, action)
   loadMore: loadMoreReducer( state, action)
})
```

Which means `state.weather` will contain whatever `weatherReducer(state, action)` returns and `state.loadMore` will contain the result of `loadMoreReducer( state, action)`. So when mapping relevant part of `state` in `mapStateToProps` you should call `state.loadMore`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => (console.log('loadMoreComponent', state), {
    state: state.loadMore // not state.weather
});
```

This is what i could get from the part of code you posted.